# querying on custom meta fields and sorting them by custom meta

Tags: wp-query

I have event posts with multiple custom date and time fields.
To pull all the events happening this week, I am querying on the different date fields.
Here is my code:

```
$today=date("Y-m-d");
$nextweek= date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+7 days"));

$args2 = array(

'post_type' => 'post',
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',

array(
'key' => 'date2',
'value' => array( $today, $nextweek ),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
),
array(
'key' => 'date3',
'value' => array( $today, $nextweek ),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
),
array(
'key' => 'date1',
'value' => array( $today, $nextweek ),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN'

)
)
);
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 ); ?>
```

When I put var_dump($query2->request) after this, I get the following string:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND ( 
  (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'date2' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) BETWEEN '2013-05-21' AND '2013-05-28') 
  OR (mt1.meta_key = 'date3' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) BETWEEN '2013-05-21' AND '2013-05-28') 
  OR (mt2.meta_key = 'date1' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) BETWEEN '2013-05-21' AND '2013-05-28') 
) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

This is pulling the correct posts, but now I want to sort the results on the date1 field. I tried this and it isn't working. I end up with all of the events posted, and not sorted either. I've also tried the 'meta_value' for orderby without luck. The values in the date1 field are in date format YYYY-MM-DD
Any help would be appreciated.

```
$args2 = array(
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_key' => 'date1',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'post_type' => 'post',
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',

array(
'key' => 'date2',
'value' => array( $today, $nextweek ),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
),
array(
'key' => 'date3',
'value' => array( $today, $nextweek ),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
),
array(
'key' => 'date1',
'value' => array( $today, $nextweek ),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN',

)
)

);

$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 ); ?>
```

When I put var_dump($query2->request) after this I get:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'date1' 
  OR (mt1.meta_key = 'date2' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) BETWEEN '2013-05-21' AND '2013-05-28') 
  OR (mt2.meta_key = 'date3' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) BETWEEN '2013-05-21' AND '2013-05-28') 
  OR (mt3.meta_key = 'date1' AND CAST(mt3.meta_value AS CHAR) BETWEEN '2013-05-21' AND '2013-05-28') 
) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Put `var_dump($query2->request);` right below the `new WP_Query` line and post the output, please.

Comment: Also, what are all these different date fields doing? Why do you need 3 (or more maybe)?

Comment: I have different date fields because one film can be scheduled to show on multiple dates. I will post separately the results from the var_dump($query2 - > request);

Comment: I'll see what I can do. Please provide the `var_dump` I asked for.

Comment: Hi s_ha_dum, I had to add the var_dump results to the question above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your meta fields are `JOIN`ing as `mt*` aliases in that query. Look for the lines like:

```
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ...
```

But the `ORDER BY` parameter is just `wp_postmeta.meta_value`, which doesn't actually make all that much sense. If that isn't a bug, I call it bad design or very limited design, but moving on.

To specifically target one of your meta values, the first one, you'd need that `ORDER BY` to be...

```
ORDER BY mt1.meta_value
```

You don't want the `meta_value_num`, by the way, because you don't have numbers. There are dashes in there. MySQL will interpret the date '2013-12-15' + 0 as just '2013'. Put `SELECT ('2013-12-15')+0` into PhpMyAdmin's SQL panel and run the query.

To do this with the data you have you will need to create a filter for your query. Add a parameter to your query...

```
$args2 = array(
  'my_orderby_field' => 'mt1',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_key' => 'date1',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  /* ... the rest */

function order_by_one_meta($orderby,$qry) {
  $myorder = $qry->get('my_orderby_field');
  if (!empty($myorder)) {
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby = str_replace($wpdb->postmeta,$myorder,$orderby);
  }
  return $orderby;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','order_by_one_meta',100,2);
```

Adding your own field to the query is a sort of a hack. I don't know it that works by design or if it is an unintentional side effect, so it does count as a somewhat dangerous piece of code. Another way to do it is simple to create the callback:

```
function order_by_one_meta($orderby) {
  $orderby = str_replace($wpdb->postmeta,$myorder,$orderby);
  return $orderby;
}
```

Apply it and then remove it where it is needed.

```
add_filter('posts_orderby','order_by_one_meta',100);
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 ); 
remove_filter('posts_orderby','order_by_one_meta',100);
```

Less dangerous, not as interesting. :(

I can't test that as I don't have your data in the database, but the SQL should be right.

I am not sure why you need multiple date keys though. Using the same key multiple times-- say `_scheduled_event_dates`-- should give you the same effect, and would make for more efficient queries and code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your expertise and help. When I try your suggestions, it pulls all of the events from the database, not just the events within the week.