# orderby meta_value breaks taxonomy term archives

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives, order, pre-get-posts

I have a People post type with a Person Type taxonomy (e.g. "Staff"). On the Person Type Term Archive pages, I want to sort by a "Sort Name" custom field. To do so, I'm using a `pre_get_posts` call:

```
<?php
function my_query_tweaks( $query ) {

    // stop immediately if we're in the admin or not working with the main query
    if( is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // order people by sortname
    if( is_post_type_archive( 'ciswa_people' ) || is_tax( 'ciswa_person_type' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'cis_sort_name' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_query_tweaks' );
```

However, when I do this, the term archive pages return no results! Commenting out the `meta_key` line brings up the correct posts but, of course, unordered.

When I look at the query WordPress is generating, I think the issue is that WordPress is trying to also *query posts* based on the meta_key rather than just ordering by it. From `$wp_query` on the relevant empty taxonomy term archive page:

```
["tax_query"]=>
  object(WP_Tax_Query)#343 (2) {
    ["queries"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["taxonomy"]=>
        string(17) "ciswa_person_type"
        ["terms"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "staff"
        }
        ["include_children"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["field"]=>
        string(4) "slug"
        ["operator"]=>
        string(2) "IN"
      }
    }
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
  }
  ["meta_query"]=>
  object(WP_Meta_Query)#344 (2) {
    ["queries"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(13) "cis_sort_name"
      }
    }
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
  }
```

...and...

```
["request"]=>
  string(498) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  fi_posts.ID FROM fi_posts  INNER JOIN fi_term_relationships ON (fi_posts.ID = fi_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN fi_postmeta ON (fi_posts.ID = fi_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( fi_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (6,10) ) AND fi_posts.post_type = 'ciswa_people' AND (fi_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR fi_posts.post_status = 'private') AND (fi_postmeta.meta_key = 'cis_sort_name' ) GROUP BY fi_posts.ID ORDER BY fi_postmeta.meta_value ASC LIMIT 0, 10"
```

Comment: Do all the posts in the taxonomy have the meta key you are trying to sort by?

Comment: This is going to be tricky, but not impossible, if you don't have that key assigned to each post. I think the solution might end up looking something like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100200/21376

Comment: The `meta_key` is required for every post but is only for alphanumeric ordering, not querying. To be clear, I have no need for a `meta_query` in this scenario, but `pre_get_posts` seems to insist on making one and I think that's what's throwing the results out of whack.

Comment: @helgatheviking see my comment on the answer below. The meta_key *is* always on every post, so I'm confused why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

`'meta_key' => 'keyname'` must be part of the query to be able to sort by its value.
Unfortunately, that will immediately result in the query being limited to posts where the key is set (its value can be empty, but it must exist).

Hence, either consider [the method s_ha_dum linked to in the question comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99891/querying-on-custom-meta-fields-and-sorting-them-by-custom-meta/100200#100200), or choose to do the sorting after the query.

Let me offer an approach to that (untested, just a concept):

```
function wpse105899_sort_posts_by_cis_sort_name( $a, $b ) {
    $a_cis_sort_name = get_post_meta( $a->ID, 'cis_sort_name', true );
    $b_cis_sort_name = get_post_meta( $b->ID, 'cis_sort_name', true );

    if ( $a_cis_sort_name === $b_cis_sort_name ) {
        return 0;
    } else if ( $a_cis_sort_name > $b_cis_sort_name ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

usort( $query->posts, 'wpse105899_sort_posts_by_cis_sort_name' );
```

Note: The above format of the conditional in the `usort` callback serves the purpose of readability. In production, it can be a one-liner:

```
function wpse105899_sort_posts_by_cis_sort_name( $a, $b ) {
    $a_cis_sort_name = get_post_meta( $a->ID, 'cis_sort_name', true );
    $b_cis_sort_name = get_post_meta( $b->ID, 'cis_sort_name', true );

    return $a_cis_sort_name === $b_cis_sort_name ? 0 : ( $a_cis_sort_name > $b_cis_sort_name ) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused because the key *is* always set to something (sometimes a number and other times "Lastname, First," but it's always set. Is that not what you mean when you say " limited to posts where the key is set?" If that's the case, it seems like that shouldn't be causing problems, but it obviously is.

Comment: Yup - that is what I meant. I now that you clarified that *it is present everywhere*, I am confused as well.

Comment: And that's the answer. (See below.) *Thank you* for the help. I would not have found this answer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

*Head desk*

I had the `meta_key` wrong. @Johannes Pille's answer was the key in that it pointed me to the fact that if the key was there this shouldn't be a problem. It was there but I wasn't using it.